# CORB cross origin request blocked how to allow in angular project

Tags: angular

i have a angular project in which i want to access data from other website in iframe, but it restrict my that you cannot access outer website data and in console it showing  cross origin request blocked (CORS), tell me how can i access other secure website data.

Comment: This is a server-side issue. See the info in the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#requesting-services-from-a-different-server-cors

Comment: can i get to know that which website is Blocking or which are allowing to access their data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment says, this is typically something you would handle from the server side. If you have no control over this, and you are using the angular server, you could create a proxy to the server in your proxy.conf.json https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Or if you have a node.js server, you could proxy the request through there by making the request from the nodejs server and piping it to the response.